# What does "return x == y" mean?

Tags: c, operators, operator-keyword, equality-operator

What does

```
return x == y;
```

mean?

Comment: It is like an if statement. So it returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `x == y` yields an integer value, either `0` (when `x` is not equal to `y`) or `1` (when `x` is equal to `y`).

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares values of two variables. The compare results in true or false, so if `x` and `y` are equal, the result is true, else the result is false.

The `return` statement returns this result from the function.

In C, false is represented for a 0,  and true for each other number (positives and negatives). So the function returns a **0** or a **1**

Comment: @dedecos, they are not written as reserved words.

Comment: @dedecos, the expression yields a semantic logical value true or false, which in C are implemented as, respectively, non-zero and zero. Note that in VB for example they are implemented as 0 and -1 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> What does
>
> ```
> return x == y;
> ```
>
> mean?

1. Do a logical comparison between `x` and `y` which evaluates to an `int` holding either `1` or `0` depending on `x` and `y` being equal or not.
2. End the function and return the result as per 1..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me make you understand what `x == y` means.

`x == y` compares `x` and `y`. The result of `x == y` will be `true` if `x` and `y` are equal, `false` otherwise.

In C, `true` is equivalent to **any non-zero value** (default is 1) and `false` is equivalent to zero.

So, if `x` is equal to `y`, `x == y` is equal to 1. Otherwise it is 0.

Finally, `return x == y` means that the value returned by the function will be `1` if both `x` and `y` are equal, `0` otherwise.

Consider the function,

```
int isEqual(int x, int y) {
    return x == y;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", isEqual(1, 1)); // 1
    printf("%d", isEqual(1, 2)); // 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, true and false are not reserved words or values, so do not write them as `true` and `false`.

Comment: I'm just explaining it. I never said they are reserved words.

Comment: Then explain properly.

Comment: This is the only answer (to date) which states that `true` is **any non-zero value**, every other answer has stated that it is `1`. Yes, `1` is a common compiler/architecture choice, but I was amazed that the only "correct" answer (yours) was down-voted by someone who doesn't include stdbool.h when playing with boolean logic - the standard core header where `bool`, `true` and `false` are defined!

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 3 The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to
>   the relational operators except for their lower precedence.108) Each
>   of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if
>   it is false. The result has type int. For any pair of operands,
>   exactly one of the relations is true.

So in this return statement

```
return x == y;
```

there is used an expression with the equality operator `==`. The value of the expression either `1` or `0` depending on whether `x` is equal to `y` or not. So the return statement returns either `1` or `0`.

You could rewrite the return statement like

```
int result = ( x == y );
return result;
```

Consider for example an if statement in the condition of which there are compared two strings

```
if ( strcmp( s1, s2 ) == 0 )
{
    puts( "The strings are equal each other." );
}
//...
```

You could write a separate function that would look like

```
int equal( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    return strcmp( s1, s2 ) == 0;
}
```

In this case the if statement would look like

```
if ( equal( s1, s2 ) )
{
    puts( "The strings are equal each other." );
}
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

This gives you a bool (or boolean). If x is equal to y, it will return true, if not, then false. This will work the same in most programming languages that use the == operator.